What is this "chip" on GoogleTV remote?
I bought a GoogleTV HD with remote, with the idea that I would make it more privacy friendly.
The remote includes a microphone, which I planned on removing using a rework station. Upon opening, where I'd expect an electret microphone, I found something that looks like a chip. It is about 3x2mm, and is mounted just above the microphone hole.

I decoded the datamatrix to: G23515ZYV2FGD27A
The other side of the PCB is covered, so far I don't know if there are any tracks on it.
I'm wondering if this is just a microphone, or some chip that if removed.  The remote may not work anymore (say an I²C chip that remote looks for, and refuses to work if not found.)
Does anyone know more?

That is the mic. And we can't know what happens if you remove it. Given there is a ferrite bead and bypass cap right next to it, it might not be an analog mic, but a digital mic that outputs data digitally in I2S or PDM or some other fashion, which in turn could be detected by the chipset that the mic is not present or working properly.

You could try and cover it with some material which reduces the sound to levels which are not useful for the algorithms anymore.

@Arsenal yes, I would also insert a needle in the hole first.

@Justme that's the point of asking if anyone recognizes is, and given nanash1 answer, that's very successful. I now have a datasheet which I'm reading, and if I'm understanding it correctly, it looks like I can remove the chip.

@user1532080 The mic datasheet does not tell you if you can remove it or not. It is a digital mic that outputs PDM data stream and it can be detected if the data stream is invalid. Removing the mic will look like invalid data stream. Now the next chip and it's software that is running there will either happily accept that or refuses to work because there is a hardware problem with the mic.

It's MEMS microphone probably made by Goertek. Here is an image of the SD18OB371-041 as example:

(Source: lcsc.com)
The markings don't seem to contain a product code:

